# How to apply custom function to grouped pandas data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

fI have a dataframe with columns for IDs, measurements and uncertainties. For some IDs I have more than one value for measurement and uncertainty, so for each ID I need to take the mean of the measurements and add the uncertainties in quadrature. I can use

```
df["measurement"] = df.groupby("ID")["measurement"].transform("mean")
```

to get the mean of the measurements, but I can't find a way to get the uncertainties added in quadrature (so a function to perform sqrt((uncertainty_1)**2 + (uncertainty_2)**2 + ...) on the uncertainties _1, _2 and so on in each ID group) to work on grouped data.

I'm looking for something like:

```
df["uncertainty"] = df.groupby("ID")["uncertainty"].transform("(custom function)").
```

I looked into using e.g. `df.groupby("ID")["uncertainty"].apply(lambda x: custom function)` but couldn't get a custom function to work (I tried a few lambda functions but the output values didn't change). Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `transform(custom_function)`

Comment: I tried a function 
```def custom_function(x):
       return np.sqrt(np.sum(x**2))
```
but it doesn't seem to work. How can I reference the individual values for the uncertainties in the function?

Comment: Please share sample data and expected output.